# How to create a bindable property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

i have a user control. I want to create a bindable property in my user control. I create a DependencyProperty as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DaiesContainer), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DateProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I then use it in my XAML:

```
<ctrls:DaiesContainer  Date="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

In my ViewModel, the get method of the Date property is called. But in my user control, Date property is not set to a value.

Comment: are you inserting the `DateTime` in XAML in a [compatible pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631811.aspx) ?

Comment: How do you know that the property is not set? You haven't registered a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) with the metadata of your dependency property. Note that the setter of the CLR wrapper is not called when the property is set in XAML, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks it's good but i have to call non static methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your dependency property implementation is missing a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) that gets called when the value of the property has changed. The callback is registered as a static method, which gets the current instance (on which the property has been changed) passed as its first parameter (of type `DependencyObject`). You have to cast that to your class type in order to access instance fields or methods, like show below.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DaiesContainer),
    new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, DatePropertyChanged));

public DateTime Date
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
}

private void DatePropertyChanged(DateTime date)
{
    //...
}

private static void DatePropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((DaiesContainer)d).DatePropertyChanged((DateTime)e.NewValue);
}
```

---

Please note also that setting a default value of the dependency property is only done once for all instances of your class. Setting a value of `DateTime.Now` will hence produce the same default value for all of them, namely the time at which the static `DependencyProperty` is registered. I guess using something more meaningful, perhaps `DateTime.MinValue`, would be a better choice. As `MinValue` is already the default value of a newly created `DateTime` instance, you may even omit the default value from your property metadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DaiesContainer),
    new PropertyMetadata(DatePropertyChanged));
```

Comment: Suggestion from 2020: it's good to use nameof(Date) in DependencyProperty declaration to  protect yourself from forgetting changing this value after changing property name

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Sure, but you are not going to write this comment at thousands of old answers?

Answer (score 0):

Make your binding Mode TwoWay

```
<ctrls:DaiesContainer  Date="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: It's not work. when i set a value to date property in C# every things are good but when i set a value to date Property in xaml it not set.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have error in XAML UserControl.

You should binding by `ElementName`, e.g.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFProject.DaiesContainer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="daiesContainer">
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, ElementName=daiesContainer}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In this case you binding to `Date` property of `DaiesContainer` class.

If you use binding without `ElementName`:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
```

UserControl  `DaiesContainer` will trying find property `Date` in `DataContext` of container this user control, and if it will not find this property, you will see `DatePicker` with empty selected value.