# Why BindingProperty get value only once from changing value of ViewModel on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I created custom view which has BindableProperty.
I bind this BindableProperty to the value of ViewModel.
I also bind Label.Text to same value.
When that value changes, Label.Text changes properly but BindableProperty doesn't get these changing.
It get first value but doesn't get changing value.

BindingProperty is like below.It has some debug code to check."ratio-ing" and "ratio" occur just once.

```
#region BarRatio BindableProperty
public static readonly BindableProperty BarRatioProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<DepthBarView, double>(
        p => p.BarRatio, default(double),

        propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ratio-ing {0}", newValue);
        },
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ratio-{0}", newValue);
                var owner = ((DepthBarView)bindable);
                owner.boxView.WidthRequest = owner.Width * newValue;
                owner.BarRatio = newValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        },
        coerceValue: (bindable, newValue) =>
        { return newValue; });
```

BindablePropery is used like below.

```
<Grid>
  <views:DepthBarView VerticalOptions="Start"
                    Fill="Blue"
                    HeightRequest="5"
                    BarHorizontalOptions="Start"
                    BarRatio="{Binding Value}"></views:DepthBarView>
  <Label Text="{Binding Value}"
       VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Any advice is helpful.
Whole repro code is here.
[test.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj0oextjnusvfoz/BitC%20-%20test.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Blimey, is that Xamarin code? It's horribly unreadable.

Comment: Are u talking about syntax like xxx:? It's normal C# feature.

Comment: No I mean the `BindableProperty`, it isn't easy on the eye.

Comment: I don't think there is big difference compared to WPF's one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629945/how-to-create-a-bindable-property-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

You needed to trigger `OnPropertyChanged` event on each update.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944217/1017153) post for howto implement `INotifyPropertyChange` interface.

Comment: in my code, NotifyPropertyChanged works like OnPropertyChanged of linked post.

Comment: when value changes Label's Text get value, but my BindableProperty not.

Answer (score 0):

This works if I commented out the line of " owner.BarRatio = newValue;"