# Custom control Bindable property don't work with ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, bindableproperty

I encounter an issue while I'm creating a Custom control in my Xamarin forms app.

I create a bindable property for the label label called "NameLabel" in this xaml file :

```xml
<Grid
    x:Class="Kwikwink.Controls.SelectedGatewayFrame"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit">
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame >
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout>
                    ...
                    <Label
                        x:Name="NameLabel"
                        FontFamily="InterMed"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource DetailTextColor}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
                ...
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

with this code in my xaml.cs file

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SelectedGatewayFrame : Grid
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty GatewayNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name),
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(SelectedGatewayFrame),
                    defaultValue: string.Empty,
                    propertyChanged: GatewayNamePropertyChanged);

        private static void GatewayNamePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (SelectedGatewayFrame)bindable;
            control.NameLabel.Text = newValue?.ToString();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get => GetValue(GatewayNameProperty)?.ToString();
            set => SetValue(GatewayNameProperty, value);
        }


        public SelectedGatewayFrame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And finaly a use it like this in other views:

```xml
<controls:SelectedGatewayFrame Name="Test string" />
```

With the string set here it work perfectly !!
My problem come when I try to bound this property to somthing in a viewmodel (`public string tmp { get; set; } = "meph";` for exemple) :
like so :

```xml
<controls:SelectedGatewayFrame Name="{Binding tmp}" />
```

or so :

```xml
<controls:SelectedGatewayFrame Name="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:NewAccessTypeViewModel}}, Path=tmp}" />
```

Then I got this error that show :

```
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Name", or mismatching type between value and property.
```

I hope this is clear enough, thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Change `public string Name` to `public string GatewayName` and or change `GatewayNameProperty` to `NameProperty`. Then adjust your xaml code to target that property; there are a few things to change. [Have a look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629945/how-to-create-a-bindable-property-in-wpf) this post, it will be helpful.

Comment: It perfectly work thanks I doesn't know there is a specific naming convention for that. Thanks a lot for your quick answer @Trevor

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help.

Comment: But know i have another issue and mybe you'll have a clue on what happen know 
when have a default value in the view model it perfectly work but if i try to set it later it stay null. 
My viewmodel is like so :
`
public Gateway CurrentGateway { get; set; }

        public NewAccessTypeViewModel()
        {
            CurrentGateway = null;
        }
        public NewAccessTypeViewModel(Gateway _gateway)
        {
            CurrentGateway = _gateway;
            Console.WriteLine($"Current gateway name => {CurrentGateway.Name}");
        }
`
@Trevor

Comment: And I try to use the Gateway.Name property that exit. The console.writline work fine

Comment: If you have other question, please open a new question.

Comment: The ViewModel need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the vue when a property's value is changed.

Answer (score 2):

As a summary, I posted an answer.

**For the first problem:**

> No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Name", or
> mismatching type between value and property.

From document [Create a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property),we know that

> Important
>
> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable
> property identifier must match the property name specified in the
> Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

So, you need to change `GatewayNameProperty` to `NameProperty` or change public string `Name` to public string `GatewayName`.

For example:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty GatewayNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GatewayName),
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(SelectedGatewayFrame),
                    defaultValue: string.Empty,
                    propertyChanged: GatewayNamePropertyChanged);


        public string GatewayName
        {
            get => GetValue(GatewayNameProperty)?.ToString();
            set => SetValue(GatewayNameProperty, value);
        }
```

**For the second problem:**

> when have a default value in the view model it perfectly work but if i
> try to set it later it stay null.

You need to implement interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0) for your view model.

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

For exmaple:

```
   public class NewAccessTypeViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {   
        Gateway currentGateway;
        public Gateway CurrentGateway
        {
            get
            {
                return currentGateway;
            }
            set
            {
                if (currentGateway != value)
                {
                    currentGateway = value;
                    OnPropertyChange(nameof(CurrentGateway));
                }
            }
        }


        public NewAccessTypeViewModel() { CurrentGateway = null; }
        public NewAccessTypeViewModel(Gateway _gateway)
        { CurrentGateway = _gateway; Console.WriteLine($"Current gateway name => {CurrentGateway.Name}"); 
        
        
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And you also need to  implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your `Gateway` .

```
public class Gateway: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // public string Name { get; set; }

    private string _name ;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChange(nameof(Name));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChange(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```